# Google Docs date capitalisation script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, formatting, date

I'm using a script that was posted here on Web Applications: [Is there a way to insert today’s date into a Google Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58981/29140). I changed the way the date is formatted to: `ddMMMyyyy` but want `01JAN2015` - the month being capitalized.

Currently my script reads and outputs like `01jan2015`.

How do I capitalize the date?

Comment: Where in my code would I insert the command .toUpperCase?

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "ddMMMyyyy");
```

into this

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "ddMMMyyyy").toUpperCase();
```

ht to Chris