# Current date as a variable in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Is it possible to add (insert) a variable for the current date into a Google Docs that would automatically update each time I open the document?

Some criteria:

- The date position should be variable, i.e. allowing me to insert the date a different positions of a page/paragraph
- The document should still be shareable, i.e. people opening my document will also be displayed with the current date

Comment: Which time zone should be used to calculate the current date?

Comment: To have it versatile, maybe defined by the user himself in the settings? Or can it be somehow fetched from the user's Google Docs settings automatically?

Comment: Just added my coding attempt. Regarding the time zone, I used GMT-5 but it could be easily changed to the one that you needs. It's not a complete solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Short answer

At this time, variables is not a built-in feature of Google Docs and Google Apps Script, the platform to extend Google Docs, does not include a class or method to handle them.

## Alternatives

### Alternative 1

One alternative is use a text pattern but you should be sure that it will match only the date that you want to update.

### Alternative 2

Another alternative is to use the class NamedRange but bear in mind that

1. moving the range will make that it lose its name<sup>1</sup>.
2. replacing text in a named range with multiple elements only works the first time<sup>2</sup>.

#### Code:

The following code, intended to be used in [a script bound to](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) a Google Document, has two main functions:

1. Insert today's date
2. Update today's date

For debugging purposes are being used

1. date and time, instead of date only.
2. custom menus to trigger the main functions.

"Known-issues": The update function replaces the whole paragraph.

To test the code, copy it, then go to your Google Docs, create a new document, click on Tools > Script Editor, select Blank Project, paste the code, save the project, assign a name, run on time to authorize the app, close your doc and open again. A new menu called "Utilities" will be displayed. From there you can call the main functions.

```
function onOpen() {
  // Add a menu with some items, some separators, and a sub-menu.
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Utilities')
      .addItem('Insert Today\'s Date', 'insertTodayAtCursor')
      .addItem('Update Today\'s Date', 'setTodayNamedRange')
      .addToUi();
}

function todayDate(){
  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"); // "yyyy-MM-dd"
}

/**
 * Inserts the today's date at the current cursor location and create a NamedRange.
 */
function insertTodayAtCursor() {
  var str = 'testToday';
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var cursor = doc.getCursor();

  if (cursor) {
    // Attempt to insert today's date at the cursor position. If insertion returns null,
    // then the cursor's containing element doesn't allow text insertions.
    var date = todayDate();
    var element = cursor.insertText(date);
    if (element) {
      var rangeBuilder = doc.newRange();
      rangeBuilder.addElement(element);
      return doc.addNamedRange(str, rangeBuilder.build()); 
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
    }
  } else {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }
}

function setTodayNamedRange(){
  var str = 'testToday';
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  // Retrieve the named range
  var namedRanges = doc.getNamedRanges();
  var newRange = doc.newRange();
  var date = todayDate();
  for(var i=0; i<namedRanges.length; i++){

    if(namedRanges[i].getName() == str){

      var rangeElement = namedRanges[i].getRange().getRangeElements();

      for (var j=0; j<rangeElement.length; j++){

        var element = rangeElement[j].getElement().asText().editAsText().setText(date);
        newRange.addElement(element);
      }
    }
  }
  doc.addNamedRange(str, newRange.build());
}
```

---

Below there are some items of different kind (questions, specifications, etc.) that could serve to get inspiration  or point to the "right direction" to find a "solution"

- [Class NamedRange - Document - Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/named-range)
- [How to use method replaceText(searchPattern, replacement) in documents Service/ text Class - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627356/how-to-use-method-replacetextsearchpattern-replacement-in-documents-service)
- [Update/Replace inline image on Google Document - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597379/update-replace-inline-image-on-google-document/)
- [Google App Scripts for Documents: insert text and add it to a named range for later retrieval - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472320/google-app-scripts-for-documents-insert-text-and-add-it-to-a-named-range-for-la)
- [Adding custom attributes to google doc text - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032362/adding-custom-attributes-to-google-doc-text)

---

**Footnotes**

- <sup>1</sup>: [Issue 3831:   Preserve NamedRanges in Docs during moving/cut-pasting](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3831)
- <sup>2</sup>: [Issue 3766:   Document App Named Ranges not working as expected](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3766)

Comment: Does that mean it is not possible?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra: IMHO, yes, it isn't possible. What could be possible is to find a workaround but it's necessary more context. I think that asking for that information should be done in comments, but I can't comment anywhere yet :)

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra: I updated my answer and my mind: from it's not possible to it's possible.

Comment: @Rubén Your code works great! In my opinion this would be great to be refactored into an installable Chrome extension (with a user setting to set the timezone). :) Thank you so much for your work!

Comment: @orschiro I'm glad to know that it worked for you. Rather than refactored into a Chrome extension, could be into a Google Docs add-on, I think.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm kind of lost, is that code an API of some type, or is it a script that is supposed to be ran by Google Docs (meaning I cannot run it from MY app)?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco: The code is intended to be used on bounded script but it could be adapted to be used from your app but that is a different question that it's very likely be more appropriate for [so].

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco I just added a link to the official guide about scripts bounds to Google Docs editor files.

Comment: I don't understand your "Alternative 1."  Do you mean a manual "search-and-replace," or are you referring to something else?

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2022, you can type `@` followed by

1. `today`
2. `yesterday`
3. `tomorrow`
4. or even a free-text date like `5 may`.

[image]

You can also specify the format by clicking on the "cog" icon.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The question is about way to insert a date that automatically updates.... Do you know if using \@today, \@yesterday or \@tomorrow will change the date every day?

Comment: Oh, good point. I'm pretty sure it won't update.