# Is it possible to make a summary sheet in Google Docs based on tags?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a document in Google Docs. It is very long and I want to tag and extract only certain paragraphs into a second document that is a summary of the first document. I want to be able to dynamically change which paragraph gets imported into the second document. Almost like an `importrange` function in Google Sheets but for Docs. Not sure if this requires apps script code or not.

Is there a way to tag the paragraph with something like "important" then in the second document tell it get all paragraphs with "important" in tag or heading?

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76370/current-date-as-a-variable-in-google-docs/76397

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Yes, it's possible but this isn't a built-in feature, so we should use an add-on or build an script.

## Extended answer

Add-ons are a way that developers share they work to add features to Google Documents, Forms, Gmail, Sheets and Slides. They could be found on the Google Chrome Web Store or in the case of Google Editors files from the Menu Add-ons > Get Add-ons...

Below is an snapshot of the results of searching summary on the Add-ons catalog accessed from a Google document. Note that the first result is "Tag, Search and Summarize"and that it has 3/5 stars rating.

[image: Search "summary" on Google Documents addons store]

Regarding the use of Google Apps Script, on my answer to [Current date as a variable in Google Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/76370/88163) I mention the use of [Class NamedRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/named-range) "to tag" certain content programmatically added, but I'm certain that could be used "to tag" selected content.